# How can I use a HiddenField to coerce integer data in WTForms?

Tags: python, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a `WTForm` class like so:

```
class MyForm(Form):
    field1 = HiddenField(default=0, validators=NumberRange(min=0, max=20)])
```

consider this markup as rendered by `WTForms`

```
<input type='hidden' name='field1' value='5'></input>
```

This does not pass the `NumberRange` validation. This is because `HiddenField`s widget class coerces the `value` attribute into a string. How can I get `WTForms` to produce this markup  such that I can perform numeric validation on the subsequent `POST`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The recommended trick is to use an `IntegerField` and change the widget to a `HiddenInput`

```
class MyForm(Form):
    field1 = IntegerField(widget=HiddenInput())
```

you can also subclass

```
class HiddenInteger(IntegerField):
    widget = HiddenInput()
```

Comment: Great idea, but it does not work well with `wtf.quick_form`. It shows the field name. Only instances of HiddenField are really hidden. Did not try that, only looked at the source.

Answer (score -6):

you can use the custom validators

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_max(value, **kwargs):   
    min = kwargs.get('min', 0)
    max = kwargs.get('max', 10)
    if str(value).isnum() and int(value) > max:
        raise ValidationError('%s is not in the range [%s..%s]' % (value, min, max))
```

or declare method clean for a field1

```
def clean_field1(self):
    value = self.cleaned_data['field1']
    try:
       ...
    except:
       raise ValidationError(...)
    return value
```

Comment: I assume this only works with Django? I'm using this in the context of a Flask app.

Comment: Django forms and WTForms are not the same thing.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. The question is asking about WTForms within the context of Flask, not Django which is a completely different framework.